# Problem with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to use the template that can be found here https://github.com/matze/mtheme but I'm running into a problem which I can't resolve. The error message says;

```
I can't find file `pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfutil-common-lists.tex'.
```

The error occurs at line 83

```
\begin{frame}{Descriptions}
  \begin{description}
    \item[PowerPoint] Meeh.
    \item[Beamer] Yeeeha.
  \end{description}
\end{frame}
```

It is the first `\item` that gives me the error. I've tried downloading the `pgfplot` package and copying it into the MiKTeX directory but it doesn't help. I have also tried downloading that file separately but I don't know in which directory to add it. Any one got any ideas?

edit:
This is what happens before \begin{document}:

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{m}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\usemintedstyle{trac}

\title{A modern beamer theme}
\subtitle{}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\institute{Institute or miscellaneous information}

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Don't download anything! MikTeX has a package manager. You can install/uninstall from there. But we need to see what you do before `\begin{document}`

Comment: I updated the post with what you asked.

Comment: @tomatpinne I get no errors with your code. Are you sure `pgfplots` is installed via the MikTeX package manager as percusse said?

Comment: Works fine here as well. I did download the latest version of the theme though, and I had to add `\usepackage{pgfplots}` to the preamble. I'll vote to close because the problem is not reproducible.